# Ansible YAML syntax error in simple playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have my first playbook and it fails. I assume it's a syntax error but as I'm not a coder I have no idea why YAML fails? Is it to do with spacing?

Here is what I have:

```
---
- name: Update all packages to the latest version
    become: true
    apt:
      update_cache: yes       
      upgrade: dist

- name: Remove useless packages from the cache
    apt:
      autoclean: yes

- name: Remove dependencies that are no longer required
    apt:
      autoremove: yes
```

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/pi/playbooks/update-apt.yml': line 3, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Update all packages to the latest version
    become: true
          ^ here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: this is not a playbook, because it doesn't contain plays (which must contain `hosts` declaration), but tasks.

Secondly: your indentation is terribly broken -- it is critical in YAML to keep declarations aligned properly (that said, the error you see is not a YAML syntax error, but an Ansible error resulting from improper data defined in a correctly written YAML file).

If you want to run it locally, it should look more or less like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Update all packages to the latest version
      become: true
      apt:
        update_cache: yes       
        upgrade: dist
        autoclean: yes
        autoremove: yes
```

Comment: #tip for getting spacing right in .yaml files: instead of blank spaces, use a character like % (easy to count). When you're done typing code, replace (Edit > Find > Replace) % with one blank space